# PHP method="post" stopped working after I added this .htaccess... Why?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've added this .htaccess to remove file extension from the URL, so instead "index.php", it would show "index" only, all the times. But after I did it, my `<form method="post">` stopped working

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Options +Indexes
AcceptPathInfo Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /

#Force from http to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [R=301]

#take off index.html
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%1 [R=301,NE,L]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]    

## hide .html extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Here's an example:

```
/* Worked before .htaccess, but not anymore */

    <form method="post" action="pwreset.php"  class="form-stacked">

/* Removing .php from action works. But there are hundreds of files and this method is not very trustworthy */

    <form method="post" action="pwreset"  class="form-stacked">
```

PS: If I use regular .htaccess rules, like this one:

RewriteRule ^index$ ./index.php [L,NC]

It won't hide .php in all cases

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` are you sure its empty

Comment: How does the web server know if it's HTML or PHP when it's posted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because you are redirecting here:

```
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

When you redirect, the request BODY doesn't always get included, you can try adding an exception for POST:

```
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

Comment: Worked! It adds .php to the file after all (when it posts), but it's the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon Lin Hi Jon, I searched all over for this same topic and came across your answer. I added it to the bottom of my .htaccess file and it did not do anything. Is there anyway we can chat or if I can show you my code. If so I  would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Paul you need to add the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]` condition to the rule that you *already have* that is redirecting. The goal with this solution is **not** redirect if the request is a POST.

Comment: @ Jon Lin   I'm not  entirely sure where that would go? Would it be under request file name [f]?   I took your code out but it was under all of this                                                                                                                               RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^er$ er.png [L]

Comment: @Jon Lin sorry for the mess. I obviously can't post it and I can not figure out where to post your code or what to modify.

Answer (score 5):

Because the `action` of your form is pointing to `/pwreset.php`. When you try to go to that page (even via a form post), the htaccess will redirect you to `/pwreset` before any PHP code runs. A redirect will drop any `POST` data from the new request.

You're going to have to change all those form actions to have the non-php version. As a short term fix, try excluding POST requests from your redirect rule

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST`

Comment: Thanks, that didn't work, only because of the missing [NC] (see @Jon Lin's answer above)