# not able to post the form because of .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

NOTE:this may be a [POSSIBLE DUPLICATE question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796522/php-method-post-stopped-working-after-i-added-this-htaccess-why) But my .htaccess is a bit different and the problem is unable to post to next page....

ie:`form action="another.php"  method="post">` or`form action="another"  method="post">` is not working.

Can any one kindly  tell me what is the change that has to be made

. my `.htaccess` page is shown below

```
RewriteEngine On

#submydomain and folders
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^jobs\.mydomain.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://jobs.mydomain.in/$1 [R=301,L]

#remove .php and ad slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://mydomain.in/jobs/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://mydomain.in/jobs/$1 [R=301,L]
# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I suspect the answer is in the question you flagged as a "possible duplicate" - you post the data to a non-existent script and Apache simply redirects the request to the real script - but not necessarily the form POST data. Try applying Jon Lin's answer to the question you highlighted at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796522/php-method-post-stopped-working-after-i-added-this-htaccess-why - see if it works when you disable the redirect for form POSTS.

Comment: @CD001 ,it is not working ..

Comment: @CD001,The same code done in another folder works

Comment: to be honest, I'm not entirely sure that what you're doing makes sense if you break the conditions down step by step ... AFAICT if `mydomain.in/jobs/` and `jobs.mydomain.in` both point the the same directory, and thus share the same `.htaccess` file - this is going to loop and hit a `500 Internal Server Error` pretty quickly. Might explain why it works in a different folder as you're not going to hit this .htaccess file there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the entire folder and uploaded the folder without .htaccess..The form worked...Later I uploaded the .htaccess (with the code that I posted in the question) and now working fine..

BUT FOR THE ANSWER AS TO WHY IT DID NOT WORK INITIALLY ,I DONT KNOW...FOR ANY ONE WHO KNOW CAN KINDLY POST..(CURIOUS TO KNOW)

Any way thanks for all those who helped me

Answer (score 0):

If you're hiding `.php` extension then you shouldn't keep it in your form action. So have your `<form>` like this:

```
form action="another" method="post">
```

Otherwise your posted URL will be externally redirected to `/another` by removing `.php` extension and your `POST` data will be lost.

Comment: I tried that also..but it is not working..Now I deleted the entire folder and uploaded a new folder without .htaccess also,it is not working..(i deleted all cookies+browsing data)

Comment: In that you case you have some other problem not a rewrite problem. Open firebug and post your form to see what HTTP status you get.

Comment: ,I got it and posted the solution also..I deleted the entire folder and uploaded the folder without .htaccess...It did not work.Then I deleted the cookies and checked ..It worked..                          Next I uploaded the .htaccess in that folder,and now it is working fine...But I dono the reason why it did not work initially???If you have any idea kindly post the solution..Any way Thanks for all your suggestion

Comment: It wasn't working because of 301 caching issues in browsers and this problem can hit you again if you don't change form action to what I suggested above. I have already explained in my answer why POST data gets lost.