# .HTACCESS - Error while retrieving PHP POST var

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am having some problems with PHP POST var and .HTACCESS files. When i use my default .HTACCESS file, i cant retrieve any POST information from PHP. But, when i delete some lines, i can get it.

The lines that i remove its the redirect from www to non-www.

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options All -Indexes -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # REDIRECIONAMENTO 301 DE WWW PARA NAO WWW
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Paginas Principais
    RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^como-assistir/?$ como_assistir.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^programas-uteis/?$ programas_uteis.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^contato/?$ contato.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^pedidos/?$ pedidos.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^termos-de-uso/?$ termos_de_uso.php [NC,L]

    # NEVER CACHE
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php|cgi|pl)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

The 02 lines that i remove and the POST its OK:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The form its OK and the var_dump it's OK too. The problem it's on .HTACCES configuration. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you issue a redirect, browsers will follow that using GET, so your POST data will be lost. Either see to it that all your forms point to the non-www address explicitly right from the start, or don’t redirect when the request method is POST.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP method="post" stopped working after I added this .htaccess... Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796522/php-method-post-stopped-working-after-i-added-this-htaccess-why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found some topic with the same problem: [this is the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796522/php-method-post-stopped-working-after-i-added-this-htaccess-why?rq=1).

I've just added on line to my .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options All -Indexes -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]
```

Thanks for all.