# form submit stops working after adding .htaccess file

Tags: php, forms, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've added the following .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/public/admin/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+?)(?:\.php)?\?caseid=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/caseid/%2/? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/caseid/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?caseid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

## hide .php extension snippet    
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=302,L]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

after adding the above code my form submit button is stopped working. HTML form tag is below

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" id="rta_parties_form">

    <?php require_once 'php_include/parties/form_parties.php';?>

</form>
```

I've tried the following as well but that also not working.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
```

Not good in Mode Rewrite stuff

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert this rule after `RewriteBase` line to skip rewrite rules for `POST` requests:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: thanks @anubhava it worked... :) cant accept answer before 12 minute lemme wait few more minutes... regards

Comment: can you kindly look at the 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035704/mode-rewrite-added-another-url-parameter-but-not-working-multiple-parameter 

question as well please

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

you can use the that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796522/php-method-post-stopped-working-after-i-added-this-htaccess-why) for compelete answer