# Mode Rewrite added another url parameter but not working (multiple parameters)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess file code below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/public/admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+?)(?:\.php)?\?caseid=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/caseid/%2/? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/caseid/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?caseid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

## hide .php extension snippet    
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=302,L]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This works perfectly fine as long as I provide 1 parameter which is `caseid` i.e

```
http://localhost/site/public/admin/PIClaimant.php?caseid=11
```

The URL above successfully changes to

```
http://localhost/site/public/admin/PIClaimant/caseid/11/
```

I've had a few pages with two parameters, which are `PIClaimant.php?caseid=11&picid=34`. Initially when I was creating htaccess file I did not pay attention to those pages `(&picid=34 only being used at a few pages 4 or 5 max)`. Now when I go back to those pages which has those parameters, they are not working not showing the content of page. They work till first parameter `PIClaimant/caseid/11/` but not with the second parameter.

Since I am not very good at this (mode rewriting) I need your help.

Any Ideas?

Comment: @anubhava are you there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are getting more complicated now :)

Try this code in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/public/admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+?)(?:\.php)?\?caseid=([^&\s]+)?\&picid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/caseid/%2/picid/%3/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/caseid/([^/]+)/picid/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?caseid=$2&picid=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+?)(?:\.php)?\?caseid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/caseid/%2/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/caseid/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?caseid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

## hide .php extension snippet    
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=302,L,NE]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: thank you @anubhava it works fine i'm happy but can I add one thing here at the moment it is showing like this(`http://localhost/site/public/admin/PIClaimant/caseid/8/43/`) is there any way I can have to add picid before `43` ie. (`http://localhost/site/public/admin/PIClaimant/caseid/8/picid/43/`)

Comment: I'm really grateful of yours thanks for taking time out and helping me

Comment: no it does not work it work its behaves weirdly like works with the very last record of that case.. but not with the rest... its like if one case has more than one picid's It would work with last one only

Comment: Can you provide URLs for which it doesn't work. I will check on your comment in an hour as I need to rush to a meeting.

Comment: no problem the working url (`http://localhost/site/public/admin/PIClaimant/caseid/8/picid/43/')

when I click other pic's it shows like this (`http://localhost/site/public/admin/PIClaimant/caseid/8/picid/28/caseid/8/picid/28/`)

Comment: Ok you're getting that long URI because you're using relative links like this: `href="PIClaimant/caseid/8/picid/28/"` instead of `href="/site/public/admin/PIClaimant/caseid/8/picid/28/"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58360/discussion-between-anubhava-and-amjad).

Comment: just one thing if you could tell me how should I learn this mode rewriting any good book that you recommend or online course etc. for basics thanks @anubhava one more time

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to the code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/public/admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+?)(?:\.php)?\?caseid=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+?)(?:\.php)?\?caseid=([^&\s]+)?\&picid=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/caseid/%2/picid/%3/? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/caseid/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?caseid=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/caseid/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?caseid=$2&picid=$3 [L,NC,QSA]


## hide .php extension snippet    
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=302,L]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

replace the code with your code see if that works