# $_POST empty after form submit with htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, post

I'm experiencing a problem with an empty $_POST array after submitting a html form.

```
<form action="interview/booking_summary" method="POST">
    <p>Ihr Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
    <p>Ihr Alter: <input type="text" name="alter" value="23" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

I think it has to do with my .htaccess file. This seems to redirect pages (e.g. file.php will be shown as file (without .php suffix)

Unfortunately I'm just working on a site I did not program by myself so I don't really understand what the htaccess file does.

It has some ReWrite Rules and I think those are responsible...

```
ErrorDocument 403 /fehler/403/
ErrorDocument 404 /fehler/404/

# PHP Settings
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
# php_flag register_globals off

RewriteEngine On
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

# Verhindert Probleme mit Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# Ordner
RewriteRule cronjobs\/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/rss/$ /cronjobs/rss.php?language=$1 [L]

# Admincenter
RewriteRule ^admin/$ /admin/index.php [L]

# Wartung
RewriteRule ^construction/ /wartung.php [L]

# Sprache
RewriteRule ^de/$ /index.php?lang=de
RewriteRule ^en/$ /index.php?lang=en

# Allgemein

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{0,2}/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /index.php?content=$2/index&lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{0,2}/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/page-([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?content=$2/index&page=$3&lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{0,2}/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /index.php?content=$2/single&id=$3&lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{0,2}/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/add-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /index.php?content=$2/single&id=$3&add=$4&lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{0,2}/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/page-([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?content=$2/single&id=$3&page=$4&lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{0,2}/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/edit-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /index.php?content=$2/single&id=$3&edit=$4&lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{0,2}/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/delete-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /index.php?content=$2/single&id=$3&delete=$4&lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{0,2}/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /index.php?content=$2/single&id=$3&permalink=$4&lang=$1 [L]

# Error Dokumente
RewriteRule ^fehler/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?content=error&code=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^booking-summary booking-summary.php    [L]


#@__HCP_END__@#
# Anything after the comment above is left alone
```

I tried to find a solution and came across this thread:
[PHP method="post" stopped working after I added this .htaccess... Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796522/php-method-post-stopped-working-after-i-added-this-htaccess-why)

And so I tried to add a rewrite rule saying:

```
RewriteRule ^booking-summary      booking-summary.php    [L]
```

But unfortunately this did not do the trick.
Can you tell me how I can make an exeption for this php file so that I can access my $_POST array?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

M

Comment: where is booking-summary.php located?

Comment: @anubhava unfortunately I cannot remove or rename my .htaccess file because then the page does not work anymore. I guess some url-paths are set ore something is redirected. If I go to localhost:8888, which should be my root, I get a page saying _Not Found -The requested URL /en/ was not found on this server._

Comment: @PanamaJack – my booking_summary is in any case called correctly. I can print other debug messages and the page otherwise loads correctly (the php-File is a contoller file for a smarty template file)...

Comment: @anubhava Thanks a lot. I could solve the problem by following Panama Jacks answer and having resolved my 'file not found' problem, where I was missing out a language prefix smarty variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps. You don't really have a rule that matches this your post URL. 
If this is your `link interview/booking_summary`, then it needs to be in the rule because I don't see one there that takes care of this already.

Add a `/` to your form URL so you don't have to go messing with existing rules.

`<form action="interview/booking_summary/" method="POST">`

Then try this rewriterule providing booking-summary is in interview folder.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^interview/booking-summary/?$ /interview/booking-summary.php [L]
```

Comment: Oh man. Just got it.
Your answer helped but not until I found out this error in my apache-log, where @Johni helped me out!
Thanks to everyone. Could not have solved this by myself!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the http code of the redirect to 307 to allow redirects with POST data:

```
[R=307,L]
```

307 tells the browser to retry the request with the new url using the same method. 302 and 303 tells the browser to use GET instead.

Comment: Where should I put this?
`# Verhindert Probleme mit Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=307]`
or in a new rule?

And could it also be that my .htaccess file is not reloaded locally? Because your answer and the one of @bulk did not work so far...
---------------------
and by the way. Should I also post an 'answer' to my question to make my code more readable?...

Comment: You only have to change this: 
```RewriteRule ^booking-summary booking-summary.php    [R=307,L]```
You could check if ```AllowOverride All``` is set for your host, if not, your local .htaccess will be ignored.

Comment: Hm, still not working. I pasted your Rule into my htaccess -> still no $_POST. 
I tried it with 'action="interview/booking_summary/"` and `action="interview/booking_summary"` but both gave me an empty POST-array.
I also tried to paste in `AllowOverride All` but unfortunately then I get an 'Internal Server Error' and my page is not displayed anymore.
But I think the htacess file is not ignored, because if I remove it my page is not working at all.

Comment: Can you post your Apache access log of this request?

Comment: Have you replaced your old rule with the one I postet, or did you just append it? You have to replace ```RewriteRule ^booking-summary booking-summary.php    [L]``` with ```RewriteRule ^booking-summary booking-summary.php [R=307,L]```

Comment: `[Tue Mar 10 17:13:33 2015] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Users/merc/Documents/folder1/folder2/folder3/project/testpage/interview, referer: http://localhost:8888/en/interview/bookings/`
I got this from apache_error.log from MAMP
So something is indeed not found. I don't understand why the php-file is called anyway...

Comment: I now added a lang specific smarty variable which stopped my apache errors from before. I don't get an error 'file not found' anymore in my log.
`action="/{$hp.lang}/interview/booking_summary"`.
But I still don't get any $_POST...

Answer (score -2):

Possibly this rule:

```
# Verhindert Probleme mit Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Is the culprit. This is redirecting URL's so they have a trailing slash, and as your form action does not have a trailing slash it's being redirected and losing the POST values in the process. Try changing the form action to this:

```
<form action="interview/booking_summary/" method="POST">
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.
I tried to do that already, but it is still no working.
I'm trying to print out my $_POST
`print_r($_POST);`
but I get `Array ( )`
And my form looks like this:
`<form action="interview/booking_summary/" method="POST">
            <p>Ihr Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
            <p>Ihr Alter: <input type="text" name="alter" value="23" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" /></p>
    </form>`