# CodeIgniter / Lost input data, $_POST is empty too

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

I am in the process of updating the long overdue CI 2.something to CI 3.1.11. So far so good except for the form data which is lost. Neither `$this->input->post('usr')` nor `$_POST` hold any values at all. Empty!

After looking through some answers I figured that my htaccess might be at fault – however it does seem to do its job alright in every other case...

I run PHP 7.3.9 on Apache2. `mod_rewrite` is on.

Here is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

It might be the htaccess file OR something else. Any ideas?

UPD: To add to confusion: the Apache log for this one request at vhost *http://esp.atlas.local* reads:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2019:23:00:42 +0200] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 301 236
>   127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2019:23:00:42 +0200] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 4592

UPD2: The confusion is cleared: I submit the form to the same URL which means it first `posts` to it and then `gets` the HTML view from it.

Anyway, I am starting to question my morality as I've tried every possible htaccess configuration (even got one from Lumen/Laravel project I run on the same machine) and I either get nothing or I get 403 forbidden (which is new, but still doesn't solve anything). Any further ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing this is already answered elsewhere.  Forget the CodeIgniter piece and focus on `$_POST` is empty... if none of the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission) are the answer, please indicate in the question and show you've handled each of them...

Comment: Probably the problem is here `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`, maybe your form action does end with a trailing slash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\_POST empty after form submit with htaccess redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967659/post-empty-after-form-submit-with-htaccess-redirect)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, but nothing had worked so far. even `php://input` is empty. Trailing slash is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so that *was* a CodeIgniter issue, as my `htaccess`, form `method`, form `URL`, etc were alright. Every other URL was working. Only $_POST was getting 403...

The problem was that csrf_token protection was set to true and as no token was present, CI has just thrown 403. I had to actually search for the error string within the installation directory to see what the problem was. `Duh`.

Here is my `htaccess` for anyone else getting into similar issues (3 lost days, Carl!)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```