# Submitting POST form to a link that contain GET parameter

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess

I have problem when i submit a POST form to a link that contain a GET parameter.

I think that the problem come from my htaccess file.

**Here my htaccess file:**

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /
# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

RewriteRule ^create$ create.php [L]
RewriteRule ^delete$ delete.php [L]
RewriteRule ^error$ error.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([\$\.A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ fetch.php?fetch=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\$\.A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/make$ fetch.php?fetch=$1&make=do [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\$\.A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/made$ fetch.php?fetch=$1&made=done [QSA,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

**My POST form:**

```
<form action="<?=$param->getsite("url")?>/<?=$product_link?>/make" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="makeit" value="yes">
     <input type="hidden" name="another" value="other">
     <input type="submit" value="Let's make it" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
</form>
```

**Make page (POST form submitted to this page):**

```
if(isset($_POST["makeit"]) && $_POST["makeit"] == "yes") {
    die("Work !");
}
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

`print_r($_REQUEST);` return only `[make] => "do"` (GET parameter) and nothing about POST form.

Comment: can you post the error log from `/var` directory

Comment: I don't know htaccess, but the answers from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796522/php-method-post-stopped-working-after-i-added-this-htaccess-why) mention the redirection 'killing' `post` data...

Comment: @PseudoAj There no error log !

Comment: @firstOne there no redirection !

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST["makeit"]) && $_POST["makeit"] == "yes") {
    die("Work !");
}
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

With this logic, it's the correct behavior that `$_REQUEST` will not contain any `POST` data. Your script is doing exactly what you asked.

When a request has POST params, it will pass the `if(isset(...))` test and will `die("Work")`.  So a request with POST params will never reach the `print_r` line.  That's why you see only GET params on that print line.

If you want to see your POST params, print before you do anything else:

```
print_r($_POST);
if(isset($_POST["makeit"]) && $_POST["makeit"] == "yes") {
    die("Work !");
}
```

Comment: If that line is never reached it means that either `makeit` parameter is not in `$_POST` or it does not equal `yes`.  I don't understand your 2nd sentence.

Comment: No `makeit` parameter are in the `FORM` like i wrote it in the code and equal to `yes`, my problem is here ! it's my main problem now ... why not reached?! read well my question please.